# no error but not responding

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, return

I am noob in Flex/Actionscript so I have the code where compiler doesn't show error but code returns nothing. Can you help me to fix it?

Main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="main()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            include 'AS/main.as';

            private function main():void {
                Label1.text = Login('irakli','password1');
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label id="Label1" x="370" y="176" text="Label"/>
</s:Application>
```

main.as

```
// ActionScript file
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

var Answer:String;

function Login(username:String, password:String){
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/hosting/index.php');

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.username = username;
    variables.password = password;
    request.data = variables;

    //handlers
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void{
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
        Answer = loader.data;
    });
    loader.load(request);

    var i:int = 1;
    while (i < 10000000000){
        if (Answer.length > 0){
            return Answer; 
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

I know about that it is good to use event handler functions, but I want that this code worked in main.mxml `Label1.text = Login('irakli','password1');`

Comment: It won't, you can't combine the asynchronous nature of URLRequest.load() with a synchronous function return value. You simply have to rethink your solution (like setting Label1.text in the Event.COMPLETE handler). A heavy while-loop like that won't do you any good, it will only make your application unresponsive while the loop executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but wanting this to work in this fashion is simply wrong.  You have no guarantee that that absurd loop will work because it could easily complete before your load operation does.  Also, having a function inline in your event handler is considered bad practice.

The correct approach to this would be to make Login a class, and listener for an event coming out of it in order to populate the text box.

This is how you could write Login as a class:

```
package {
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class Login extends EventDispatcher
    {
        public function Login(username:String, password:String):void
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/hosting/index.php');
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            variables.username = username;
            variables.password = password;
            request.data = variables;

            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);
            loader.load(request);
        }

        private function loadCompleteHander(evt:Event):void
        {
            // set the event on out of the class
            dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

So then you would use this like this:

```
var login:Login = new Login('irakli','password1');
login.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,setTheText);

function setTheText(evt:Event):void
{
    Label1.text = evt.target.data;
}
```

Of course if you don't want listeners in your mxml (and I can't understand why that would be), then I think your best approach would be to pass the target textField into your Login function and let it set the text in the inline handler.  Something like:

```
Login('irakli','password1',Label1);
```

main.as

```
// ActionScript file
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.text.TextField

var targetTF:TextField;

function Login(username:String, password:String,textField:TextField){
    targetTF = textField;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/hosting/index.php');

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.username = username;
    variables.password = password;
    request.data = variables;

    //handlers
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void{
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
        targetTF.text = loader.data;
    });
    loader.load(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a bunch of problems:

1. Your function does not specify a return type, or an access modifier
2. [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) is asynchronous, but it appears you want your code to run synchronously.
3. Your anonymous function on the URLLoader complete event will not execute in-line; so the last half of your method will execute before the complete handler.

---

Try modifying things to break them up into two functions, like this:

```
public function Login(username:String, password:String):void{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/hosting/index.php');

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.username = username;
    variables.password = password;
    request.data = variables;

    //handlers
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete); 
    loader.load(request);
}

public function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void{
 var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
 Answer = loader.data;
 label1.text = Answer;
}
```

In your creation complete handler, try something like this:

```
Login('irakli','password1');
```

It calls the method.  And the value of the label is set in the complete handler.  Your method of waiting for the results is creating, but unnecessary.

Comment: Did you mean to give the second function a name? :)

Comment: Yes, I most certainly meant to give the 2nd function a name.  I think @constantiner fixed my typo, so much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

uiiuiui. there are multiple things wrong here.

try not to use variables/functions with capital letters

```
private var _myVar:String = "string";

private function myFunction():void
{

}
```

declare you variables/functions as either private/public/protected

define return type of your function

```
private function login (username:String, password:String):String
{

}
```

you don't hace to use includes here - just put your login() method in the Main.mxml

don't use anonymous functions in event handlers - define a custom **named** function instead:

```
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

private function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
   // do sth here ...
}
```

and don't use a while loop to wait for the result of your URLLoader - that's what the eventlistener is for.

best thing would be, if you create a Login class which handles the login-backend-communication and returns the result (ok or not ok) depending on the answer of the server.

```
package
{
  public class Login
  {
    public function Login()
    {

    }

    public function doLogin(username:String, password:String):void
    {
       // do loader stuff here ...
       loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoginResponse);
    }

    private function onLoginResponse(evt:Event):void
    {
       // check answer from server
       if (server.response == "ok")
       {
         dispatchEvent(new Event('logged_in'));
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't define a function as private/pubic/protected/internal unless it's a class member.

Comment: he should just add them to the Main.mxml andd then he could ... as i wrote

Comment: sorry, I don't use mxml files so I wasn't aware that you could define private/public etc.. in them. So does the code in `fx:script` wrap into a class?

Comment: yes. don't exactly know what the include does to the code (never used it myself) but i think the functions will become class members and could therefore be public/private/protected

Comment: @pkyeck the include is like a copy and paste. Functions & variables defined in the include will become class members for the class they are included into; in this case that is the main app.  There should be no problem defining access modifiers in the include file; although if you're in a library project make sure not to include the include files in the final SWC, or else the compiler will treat them as classes not "code snippets". I wouldn't say using 'includes' is wrong. Flex Framework uses them for shared metadata; and some people use a similar approach to separate MXML From ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this is one of the ugliest ActionScript code I've ever seen :( Can't imagine what language you're came from. PHP?

First of all, please read some fundamentals before writing code.

About code in particular:

- What is the purpose of `include` statement in your code? Why not inline code in the `Script` block. Your way of code modularization is the best idea to make code obscured and hard to read and support.
- Please read and [follow ActionScript naming and coding conventions](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions). It is necessary when you share your code with somebody (team member or SO).
- Your `Login` method isn't return anything. Why do you expect `Login('irakli','password1')` will produce any text?
- Please understand asynchronous nature of Flash and ActionScript. To understand it better, please don't inline event handlers but create separate methods for them.